# Linux-image: problems with any updates

Tags: ubuntu

VPS with ubuntu 16.04. Used Apache, two versions of PHP - 5.6 (active) and 7.0. 
I need to install the SOAP module for PHP 5.6. The command:

```
apt-get install php-soap

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libssl1.0.2 linux-headers-4.4.0-108 linux-headers-4.4.0-108-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-21 linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81
  linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-83 linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87
  linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-89 linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-92
  linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic (4.4.0-121.145) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.121.127); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic (4.4.0-108.131) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The problem with linux-image appear with any commands with apt-get install.

In one of the solutions to the problem were advised to remove all versions of files in the folder /root (ex config-4.4.0-89-generic, initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic), with the exception of the last two versions, but it didn't help - when apt-get update and apt-get upgrade re-downloaded all the files and again there is a problem with dpkg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Answer maybe to late, but check this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition .

I think your problem is, your /boot partition is full (100%), check it with command
`df -h`

Answer (score 0):

The dependency is causing it; look for the 'linux-modules' package ("linux-modules-") and purge that instead.

```
sudo apt purge -f linux-modules-4.4.0-108-generic
```